# href on the same page not works on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to provide an nav bar with hyperlinks which links to another section in the same page,

But it didn't work.

When I cliked the service link on the nav bar, the url has changed in the broswer from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/#.service`

But the browser didn't move the window to the service section

Here's my nav bar haml code

```
    %li
      %a{href: "#"} Home
    %li
      %a{href: "#.service"} Service
```

Here is the page's `haml` source code

```
.service
  / Start service
  .container
    %h2.head SERVICE
    %p.para Et harum quidem rerum et expedita distinctio.
    .service-top
      .row
        .col-md-3.col-sm-3
          / Service top item
          .text-center
            .simg
              / Images
              %img.simg-one.animated{alt: "", src: "img/service/12.png"}/
              %img.simg-two.animated{alt: "", src: "img/service/11.png"}/
            / Heading
            %h3 Mail Box
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on [HTML anchor tags](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html)

---

You need to link to an `anchor`, which is defined as a `name` or `ID` in your HTML:

```
%a{href: "#service"}

.service{ id: "service" }
```

As I was researching this answer, I actually discovered [you shouldn't use `name` any more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp), but `ID` instead (HTML5 doesn't support `name`):

> ```
> name
> Not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute instead. Specifies the name of an anchor
> ```

Comment: Can you please supply link discussing the deprication of `%a name`

Comment: It's on the answer - w3schools